# How do you set up OpenCV to run using the ijava kernel in juypter notebook?

Tags: opencv, anaconda

I have some Java code that would make more sense to run as a notebook so,

I have installed juypter notebook installed with the ijava kernel using anaconda, but I can't figure out how to set up a OpenCV notebook, despite having OpenCV instances installed in anaconda and on my local pc.

The only thing I have found is this http://blog.hellonico.info/java/jupyter_and_opencv/ but I can't get it to work.

Comment: you've ran far away from the"well trodden path". if using notebooks, stick with (excellently supported) opencv python code, not an esoteric java thing

Comment: I have some legacy code that would make better sense to have as a notebook, without rewriting it in python. I know others have done it in the past. I would just like to know how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed jdk 11 on my machine and installed ijava, as per instructions.

Where I was failing was using lein and conjure, so I downloaded the lein.bat from https://leiningen.org/

Ran:

lein install

lein new jvm-opencv hellocv-j

opened java_sample.ipynb and chose java as the kernel and reset and reran the notebook and it worked fine.

Now to port my code to the jupyter notebook!